# AWS Redshift Spectrum(External table) - Varchar datatype assigned to a column is not able to handle both array and string data for same column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Task: Trying to load a bunch of JSON files from s3 buckets to Redshift using Redshift Spectrum.
Problem: JSON objects in few files are having data wrapped with Square brackets but other JSON files are having the same objects without square brackets. Is there a way to consume data both with/ without square brackets "[ ]" while creating an external table using the Redshift spectrum table?

JSON FILES to be consumed:

File 1:   `"x":{"y":{ "z":["ABCD"]}}`

File 2:   `"x":{"y":{ "z":"EFGH"}}`

**Case 1**

When column z is defined as an array, I am missing out the data from JSON file  which are "without square brackets"

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.table
(x struct<y:struct<z:array<varchar(256)>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'dots.in.keys'='true') STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location 's3://****'
```

Query: `Select c  from spectrum.table t ,  t.x.y.z c;`

**Case 2**

When column z is defined as varchar (without declaring as an array), below is the error:

Create Statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.table
(x struct<y:struct<z:varchar(256)>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'dots.in.keys'='true') STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location 's3://****'
```

Query: `Select   regexp_replace( t.x.y.z ,'\\([\\"])', '' )  from spectrum.table t;`
or `Select t.x.y.z from spectrum.table t`;

```
 [XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Spectrum Scan Error
 Details:
-----------------------------------------------
 error:  Spectrum Scan Error
 code:      15001
 context:   Unsupported implicit cast: Column ('x' 'y' 'z'), From Type: LIST, To Type: VARCHAR, 

 ----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  Hitting the same issue

Comment: This is what AWS support said -.  After testing many alternative it turns out unfortunately it won't be possible to defined a external table schema in a way that it would be able to read json data with one of the column is defined as an Array or String.

So I got the JSON data copied from S3 to Redshift directly and worked on the column to extract the required piece of the data.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info!